# Wireless dkms module failed building, kernel installed anyway, Ethernet doesn't work either

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

Problem is on Arch Linux. Upon installation of kernel 5.10.2-arch1-1 build of broadcom-wl failed. Now I have no internet, and both wireless and Ethernet are not working. Ethernet controller is Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411, wireless controller is Broadcom BCM43228. A

Comment: See if this solution helps you:   https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218172

Answer (score 0):

**WIFI**

You can install the [`broadcom-wl`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=broadcom-wl) from the [community testing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/official_repositories#community-testing) repository (version 6.30.223.271-251).

The `broadcom-wl-dkms` is the DKMS  alternative to  `broadcom-wl`, available from testing and the community testing repository.

Archlinux wiki: [broadcom-wl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless#broadcom-wl)

**ETHERNET** (It should be done first, to get an Internet connection)

> [Gigabyte Motherboard with Realtek 8111/8168/8411](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Ethernet#Gigabyte_Motherboard_with_Realtek_8111/8168/8411)

> With motherboards such as the Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3, booting with IOMMU off (which can be the default) will cause the network interface to be unreliable, often failing to connect or connecting but allowing no throughput. This will apply to the onboard NIC and to any other pci-NIC in the box because the IOMMU setting affects the entire network interface on the board. Enabling IOMMU and booting with the install media will throw AMD I-10/xhci page faults for a second, but then boots normally, resulting in a fully functional onboard NIC (even with the r8169 module).

> When configuring the boot process for your installation, add `iommu=soft` as a [kernel parameter](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters) to eliminate the error messages on boot and restore USB3.0 functionality.